# How to manage large set of Outlook canned responses/signatures for several users on network?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

In our small office with 6 people we use Outlook signatures as canned responses. So we have a signature for when someone asks "question A", for when we send out "form DB7-ET", etc…

The situation right now is that there is one Excel file with all of these canned responses (about 30). The people in the office have copied them to their personal Outlook signatures.
Whenever something changes in a canned response, someone sends an e-mail to everyone, asking them to update their signatures accordingly.

This feels very outdated and error-prone to me and therefore I am looking for a way to manage 30 or so signatures/canned response centrally. I found solutions to do this for one default company signature, but I am looking for a way to synchronise all signatures of every Outlook user in our office.

A solution that manages the canned responses centrally without using the Outlook signature functionality is also welcome.

Comment: You could use a script to copy the updated signature files to each user's Signatures folder in their AppData folder structure.